# Origin and meaning of the surname "Babjak"

Tags: etymology

I have a question regarding the surname "Babjak". I've been researching its origin and meaning for a while now, but I haven't found anything substantial. As far as I know, it traces its roots to Slovak origins. I was wondering if the name (or any of its variants: Bebjak, Bebiak, etc.) had a meaning in the Slovak or in any other Slavic languages. It certainly does not seem to mean anything in Hungarian, yet it's not an uncommon name in Hungary.

What is the etymology of this surname?

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be little doubt that the origin is a Slavic nickname. This is because in ancient times it was very common among Slavs to give nicknames in addition to the official name received at baptism. In case of the Cossacks, this had security reasons in order to hide their origin from oppressing forces. The result was a huge number of nicknames, which subsequently became the basis for surnames. (2)

Most sources seem to agree that the most likely origin for the name is the Slavic word "baba", which can mean old women, grandmother, witch, and midwife. This latter can indicate that the word was used as a metonymy referring to an occupation or job.

The -iak part at the end is a diminutive or augmentative. (4)

I. Ukrainian link

Surnames like "Баб'як" (Bab'jak) and "Бабяк" (ba'bjak) are common in Ukraine. (1,4)

I.1. The surname Babiak may have its origin in the old common nickname "baba", a married woman of the lower classes. (2)

I.2. Other possibility is the word "бабак", which refers to the bobak marmot aka steppe marmot. This nickname could have been given to sedentary, thick, or lonely people living an unsociable, introverted lifestyle. (2)

I.3. Other origin may be the word "бабка", which means dragonfly. (1)

II. Polish link

Babiak exists in Polish. (3)

II.1. The root can be the word "baba", meaning woman, old woman, or hag. "Babiak" may have originated as a variant of "babiarz" (womaniser, skirt-chaser). Alternatively, it may have been a matronymic tag for the bastard son of an unwedded lass. (3)

II.2. The surname may have been formed from the male baptismal name "Baba", which was very common in Poland in the XIV century. Many variants derived from this origin, and are often found in documents: Novgorod peasant Iwashko Babin, 1495; Moscow homeowner Gregory Babin, 1504 (2)

III. Slovak link

"Babiak" and "Babiák" can be found in the Slovak language. (4)

III.1. "baba" means old woman; can be used as derogatory term for gutless men. (5)

III.2. Other sources suggest the origin word to be "bob" (beans) or "bobo" (bogeyman). (5) The Hungarian environment may have caused the "o" to transform into "a", however this is unlikely as "Bobiak" cannot be found in contemporary Slovak. (4)

Sources:

(1) the reply here by user "Yellow Sky"

(2) www.analizfamilii.ru/Babyak/proishozhdenie.html

(3) forum reply by user "Polonius3" found at link
www.polishforums.com/genealogy-6/meaning-last-name-surname-23560/78/

(4) forum.index.hu/Search/showArticleResult?topic_id=9056730&aq_ext=1&aq_text=babjak

(5) edit.elte.hu/xmlui/bitstream/handle/10831/8853/ne35_13ml.pdf?sequence=1

As a side note, the word "baba" means baby in Hungarian. However, it used to be employed as a term of affection as well between lovers and newly weds - much like in English. Many Hungarian folk songs contain the term "babám" (my baby) often referring to young women. However, contemporary Hungarian shuns this expression as it is considered archaic. On the other hand, "bába" means midwife, a term still used occasionally. Some traditional Hungarian folk fairy tales refer to the recurring character of the witch as "vasorrú bába" (iron nosed old women).

Answer (score 1):

Being a native speaker of Ukrainian which is very close to Slovak, and taking into account that the surnames like that (Баб'як [bab'jak], Бабяк [ba'bʲak]) are common in Ukraine too, I can explain the meaning of it. "Баба" means "woman", "бабка" means "dragonfly", so the surname is derived from one of those.

http://www.analizfamilii.ru/Babyak/proishozhdenie.html

Comment: +1, could also be given to children of a widow or a woman whose husband was away for a long-term (usually, military) service.

Answer (score 0):

Babiak,Бабяк is of Ukrainian origin.  My father and his father (my grandfather) came from Mala Plavycha a village close to the city Lviv Ukraine.  Doubt there is any connection to Russia/Russian.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! This post would benefit from adding further details. Being a one-line post, it may attract downvotes and criticism. Please [edit] it to add further relevant information — preferably with references to credible sources.

Answer (score -3):

All wrong. Babjak is russinian surname derived from russinian word bab, meaning bean. Thus babjak was a farmer growing beans. Russinians are small slowly vanishing nation living as minority in Slovakia and Ucraine

Comment: Are you sure bean is "bab", not "bob"? Such vowel shift is untypical in Slavic languages.